# react-redux updates redux store but not component state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutability, immutable.js

Amount updates in redux store but not in component state .what wrong i am doing?

Amount is 0 in component state

### [image]

[image]

**Component**

```
import React from 'react'; import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class testComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {
            name: 'shirt',
            quantity: 2,
            rate: 4,
            amount: 0,
        }
    }

    computeAmount() {
        this.props.dispatch({
            type: 'COMPUTE_AMOUNT',
            paylod: { rate: this.state.rate, quantity: this.state.quantity }
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                AMOUNT IN REDUX = {this.props.amount}
                <div>
                    <input value={this.state.name} />

                    quantity <input value={this.state.quantity} />

                    rate <input value={this.state.rate} />

                    amount <input value={this.state.amount} />
                </div>
                AMOUNT IN STATE = {this.state.amount}

                <div> <button onClick={(e) => this.computeAmount(e)} >Compute Amount</button> </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

testComponent.propTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    amount: PropTypes.number.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        amount: state.rootReducer.testReducer.amount
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(testComponent)
```

**Reducer**

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

let initialState = {amount : 0}

const testReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {

        case 'COMPUTE_AMOUNT':
            action.paylod.amount = action.paylod.rate * action.paylod.quantity

        //Try 1
        return { ...state, ...action.paylod }

        //Try 2
        // return update(state, { $set: action.paylod });

        //Try 3
        //return update(state, { $merge: action.paylod });

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default testReducer;
```

**Thanks @Mohamed Binothman**

### **fully working [Reducer](https://gist.github.com/pawarvijay/e51adbff8989c165f1b29bb06c3eb589) [component](https://gist.github.com/pawarvijay/a7acac49d93c7ea867e9ed7c32e0eff4)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your value of amount not connected to the Redux state, that is the problem.
To make your component State sync with the Redux State, you need to do the following :

1- Declare the values that you need to get from redux state on the connect.

```
const mapStateToProps = (store) => {
      return {
        amount: store.yourReducer.amount
      }
}
testComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(testComponent)
```

2 : Add componentWillReceiveProps to your Component

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
      if (this.state.amount !== nextProps.amount) {
          this.setState({amount: nextProps.amount})
      }
}
```

Comment: still not working ,also i set `const testReducer = (state = {amount : 0}, action) => {` in reducer .still something is missing

Comment: can you put the full code of the Component and the Reducer

Comment: awssseome its working now , it took me about  6 hours to figureout :).Thanks a lott

Comment: please accept my edit ..then it will be one compact answer

Comment: ignore the step number 2, no need for this, look to my last comment

Answer (score 0):

Add componentWillReceiveProps to your Component

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
      this.setState({amount: nextProps.amount})
}
```

and return the constructor to be

```
constructor(props) {

        super(props);


        this.state = {
            name: 'shirt',
            quantity: 2,
            rate: 4,
            amount: 0,
        }
    }
```